# Json Serialization of Large data object using c#

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest, jsonserializer

I am working on an application where I want to serialize a large data set object. The problem is that it serializes the object very slowly and my file uploaded on FTP is incomplete JSON. Here is my code.

```
var warrantyRecord = JsonSerializer.Serialize(warrantyData.WorkOrders);
using var stream = toStream(warrantyRecord);
var fileUploadPath = _kubotaHistoryOptions?.RootPath + getKubotaInvoiceHistoryFileName(location.Item1);
await _iFtpClientService.SendFileAsync(_kubotaHistoryOptions?.FTP, stream, fileUploadPath);
```

When I go and check the file it is always incomplete. When I try to debug my code check for variable warrantyRecord it seems like data is still loading and it takes to time to serialize the whole object. My Json always looks like this at the end. From start it is good the ending tags are always missing.

```
  ...."Cost":52.0097,"Price":58.6600,"LineAmount":58.66000000,"Discount":0.0000,"SaleTax":0,"LineTotal":58.66000000},{"LineID":"4","LineType":"Core Ret","ItemNumber":"66-17R","ItemDesc":"Tire","Quantity"
```

Comment: Did your application crash perhaps? How did you check that `warrantyRecord` is truncated instead of the uploaded file? Or that `toStream` didn't produce a truncated buffer?

Comment: When I try to debugg the warrantyRecord variable my application crashed

Comment: You can eliminate both `warrantyRecord` and `toStream` by using the `Serialize` overload that serializes to `Stream`. You can create a `MemoryStream` and call `JsonSerializer.Serialize(ms, warrantyData.WorkOrders)`. Make sure to reset the position to 0 before uploading

Comment: I try to figure it out somehow and it keeps on loading. I am uploading this JSON file to FTP where I can see my JSON is incomplete.

Comment: `debugg the warrantyRecord` variables don't get executed. If `Serialize` crashed, what was the exception? If it did, you wouldn't see an incomplete file though

Comment: `uploading this JSON file to FTP where I can see my JSON is incomplete` you already wrote that. It's *far* more likely that `SendFileAsync` crashed or timed out. What does that method do?

Comment: That method do an upload process to ftp that is it

Comment: It's also possible that `toStream` has a bug that truncated the data. You haven't posted the code that's most likely to cause the problem

Comment: `to that is it` how? There's no `that is it` with either FTP or .NET and FTP. There are no native FTP classes and FtpWebRequest tries to make FTP look like HTTP, a *completely* different protocol. It doesn't even exist in .NET Core because the differences are too big. Perhaps `SendAsync` throughs but hides errors with a `catch {}`? Perhaps it uploads the bytes as text instead of binary? Perhaps it sends the wrong size?

Comment: I have already added try catch block but not exception there

Comment: Post your code, don't describe it. System.Text.Json is used by all ASP.NET Core applications. It's far more likely that any bugs are in the code you haven't posted

Comment: You can check your assumption by saving the JSON string to a file. Is it still truncated? What if you use `.Serialize(Stream,...)` to write to a file stream?

Comment: Let me check it with the memory stream you mentioned above.

Comment: Please show the code for `toStream`

Comment: For large amounts of data I would really consider either compressing the json or use a binary format. [This comparison](https://blog.devgenius.io/serialization-performance-in-net-json-bson-protobuf-avro-a25e8207d9de) suggest protobuf.net is roughtly half in size/time/memory compared to system.Text.Json. You should also serialize directly to a stream to avoid some overhead.

Comment: If you write the stream to a file, will the file be complete?